# How do I make a folder whose contents are just a reference to another a folder?

Tags: bash, directory, shared-folders

I have a folder, x, whose path I don't want to touch, but I want to have a reference to all of the content within x so that I can upload it to github from a different path. How can I make a new folder, y, that holds in memory a reference to x? I plan on only modifying things in folder x, not folder y; folder y just reading the contents of folder x.

Comment: `ln -s /path/to/folder /path/to/reference/folder`

Comment: @Terrance's comment was helpful in guiding me toward this realization: hard links cannot be made to directories. I think that is what I wanted to do. The problem with the soft link is that the directory gets uploaded to github as just a path. I guess I'll just have to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Linking as @Terrace said would not work because if you were to change folder `x` folder `y` would also change. Why not just duplicate it?

*Hope this helps*